# The current environment does not support the specified persistence type firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I get this error. "The current environment does not support the specified persistence type." I was testing my app and saw that when a user is logged in it's logged in everywhere. So I'm trying to implement sessions on node.js express using firebase hoping this will solve it. My code is this:

```
router.post("/login", function (req, res) {
email = req.body.email;
password = req.body.password;

firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function () {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {

            res.redirect("/home");
        }
    });
});});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only `none` persistence is supported in a node.js environment (it is the default setting). The reason for this is because when Firebase Auth client library is used in a server environment, you could have multiple users logging in and you don't have the notion of a currentUser that is persisted on the backend server (this would cause one user to clobber the other). Session persistence can be modified on the client only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what should i use to authenticate users individually?

Comment: The API is optimized to authenticate the user on the client side. In that case you always send the ID token to your server and verify it with the admin SDK before serving restricted resources. You could also send it to your backend but you will end up having multiple users going through that flow. In that case, you are expected to manage the session. The user session will not refresh on its own every hour.