# Firebase Hosting Web Node Js App using Firebase Auth, Auth Session is kept across devices?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I have a Node Js (Express Js) web app deployed on Firebase Hosting. The app only uses Firebase Auth to control user access to the app. The problem is that when I log in, the session is kept in the server. That means, if I open my app in another device I'm logged in. I want my app to not keep session across devices.

To make it clearer. I log in to my web app opened in my laptop. Everything works fine. Then I open the app in my phone's browser, the app is already logged in because I logged in my laptop.

Help me, I can't find an answer online. The only thing I have come across are session cookies but I don't know if that is the solution.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**
This is the code I'm using to log in my users. I'm using Express Js and I'm logging in the users in the backend in my index.js route.The code below is executed after a log in form submit with post.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.email, req.body.password).then(function(data){
            db.collection("usuarios").doc(auth.currentUser.uid).get().then(function(doc) {
                if(doc.data().roles.includes(1) || doc.data().roles.includes(0)){
                    auth.signOut().then(function(data){
                        view = 'index';
                        context = {
                            error: true,
                            title: "Home",
                        };
                        res.render(view, context);
                    }).catch(function(error) {
                        view = 'index';
                        context = {
                            error: false,
                            title: "Home",
                        };
                        res.render(view, context);
                    });
                } else { //The user has been logged in and has the correct permissions
                    view = 'admin';
                    context = {
                        error: false,
                        username: firebase.auth().currentUser.email,
                        title: 'Admin',
                        roles: doc.data().roles,
                    };
                    res.render(view, context);
                }
            })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    view = 'index';
                    context = {
                        error: false,
                        title: "Home",
                    };
                    res.render(view, context);
                });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            view = 'index';
            context = {
                error: true,
                title: "Home",
            };
            res.render(view, context);
        });
```

Comment: "I log in to my web app opened in my laptop. Everything works fine. Then I open the app in my phone's browser, the app is already logged in because I logged in my laptop." That is not the behavior I usually get when implementing Firebase Authentication; I have to normally sign in on each unique device/browser combination. Can you update your question to include the [minimal code that any of us can run to reproduce the behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have added the log in code I use. From the documentation I have read, I think logging in the users in the client side javascript and verifying the ID tokens of the user in the backend will fix the problem. I have not tried it but I'm trying to find an easier solution.  Thank you.

Comment: The you shared logs the user in with `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.email, req.body.password)`. What's the problem you have when you run this code?

Comment: Oh well, it does not generate any problem. This is the only code I'm using to log in my users, and it works fine. The problem is the session stays across devices. I don't know if it is because I'm logging in the users in the backend instead of the front end. I don't have any other code that controls sessions or logging in users. I'm using node js (express js)  in the back end.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this documentation for firebase Auth:

> You can choose one of three types of Auth state persistence on a specified Firebase Auth instance based on your application or user's requirements.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#supported_types_of_auth_state_persistence

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but as I'm using node js, I get this message when I try to change the Auth state persistence to session or local: 'The current environment does not support the specified persistence type.'

Comment: I see, in that case please refer to this answer from someone having the same problem in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45852689/8161471

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try doing that.